# ng-disabled does not enable when condition turns false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The way my code works is, I have a table that displays a list of modules and a checkbox to the left of it. Initially my `val` (inside the controller) is blank. So there will be no rows displayed inside the table of the directive.

But when I select one of the module values in the table , the submodules having the module value that I clicked get displayed (as it changes the value of `val`) inside the directive table, and the checkboxes to its side are set to disabled.

Now when the checkbox next to the module I clicked is selected, then the corresponding values `$scope.WW` or `$scope.APS` etc. turn true. But when it turns true, the directive table checkboxes don't get enabled, because inside the `ng-disabled` I have given the condition as `submod.mod`. So I expect whenever the WW, or APS etc. values turn true, these should also get disabled. But that does not happen. Please help.

Following is my controller where my data is defined as well as the functions that are going to be used:

```
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.values = [{"name" : "1" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "2" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "3" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "4" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "5" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "6" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "7" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "8" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "9" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    ...
                ];
                $scope.val = "";
                $scope.WW = false; ... ;$scope.APS = false;

                function tester(param) {
                    $scope.val = param;
                }

                function modifyValues(param , sel) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.values.length; ++i) {
                        if (param == $scope.values[i].mod) {
                            $scope.values[i]["selected"] = sel;
                        }
                    }
                }

                function deselect(param) {
                    console.log(param);
                    if (param == 'WW') {
                        $scope.WW=false;
                        console.log("Triggered WW");
                    }  
                    else if (param == 'APS') {
                        $scope.AG=false;
                        console.log("Triggered AG");
                    }
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                    else if (param == 'USERSPACE') {
                        $scope.USERSPACE=false;
                        console.log("Triggered USERSPACE")
                    }
                    else
                        console.log('Bhaad me jaao')
                }

                $scope.deselect = deselect;
                $scope.modifyValues = modifyValues;
                $scope.tester = tester;
            })
```

Here is the body of my application:

```
<body ng-app="anApp" ng-controller='aCtrl'>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Check</td>
                <td>Module</td>
                <td>Last Start TS</td>
                <td>Last End TS</td>
                <td>Log</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='WW' ng-click="modifyValues('WW' , !WW)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('WW')">WW</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='EMA' ng-click="modifyValues('EMA' , !EMA)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('EMA')">EMA</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='APN' ng-click="modifyValues('APN' , !APN)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('APN')">APN</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='APS' ng-click="modifyValues('APS' , !APS)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('APS')">APS</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='AG' ng-click="modifyValues('AG' , !AG)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('AG')">AG</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='USERSPACE' ng-click="modifyValues('USERSPACE' , !USERSPACE)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('USERSPACE')">USERSPACE</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='OTHER' ng-click="modifyValues('OTHER' , !OTHER)"></td>
                <td><a ng-click="tester('OTHER')">OTHER</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <my-table array="values" value="val"></my-table>
    </body>
```

Notice the directive my-table. It is defined below:

```
app.directive('myTable' , function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {
                        array: '=',
                        value: '='
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'template.html'
                }
            });
```

Whose template is:

```
<table ng-controller='aCtrl' border="1" ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶"̶ >
    <tr>
        <td>Check</td>
        <td>Submodule</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="submod in array" ng-if="submod.mod == value">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="submodule" value="{{submod.name}}"
                   ng-model="submod.selected" ng-click="deselect(submod.mod)"
                   ng-disabled="submod.mod">
        </td>
        <td>{{submod.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what alternative do you suggest then?

Comment: Check the anchor links in the main table. When they are clicked, a JS function is triggered, which changes the `$scope.value` inside my controller, which when inside `ng-if` of directive checks whether my value equals that particular object's (inside the array) `mod`. So I bind `$scope.value` using ng-model inside the directive

Comment: The `ng-model` directive on the `<table>` element is useless and distracting.

Comment: Have you tried to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`? I knew that ng-if could create some problem in angularjs.